# C# is sending wrong parameters to mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, decimal

I am sending parameters from c# to the mysql database. Problem is that I have decimal value in c# ( for example : 45.335 ) but when I am sending it to the mysql it keeps sending it in this format ( 45,335 )
What am I doing wrong?

```
    MySqlConnection con = null;
    MySqlCommand cmd = null;


    con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=data;uid=root;pwd=*****");
    con.Open();
    cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into data values (null, ?ParName , ?Parname2);", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ParName", OSGconv.deciLat);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Parname2", OSGconv.deciLon);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost certainly a localisation issue; in the UK we use a full stop as a decimal point, but on the continent, a comma is used instead. Check the country settings for your app and database.

Comment: I have tried it and I can see that C# is sending value as 5.3 and when it goes into query it gets formated to 5,3 and in my table I only see 5. Can you show me on my example what to do

Comment: what is the data type on that column?